# Reading data a block at a time, synchronously

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, typescript2.0

What is the nodejs (typescript) equivalent of the following Python snippet?  I've put an attempt at corresponding nodejs below the Python.

Note that I want to read a chunk at a time (later that is, in this example I'm just reading the first kilobyte), *synchronously*.

Also, I do not want to read the entire file into virtual memory at once; some of my input files will (eventually) be too big for that.

The nodejs snippet always returns null.  I want it to return a string or buffer or something along those lines.  If the file is >= 1024 bytes long, I want a 1024 character long return, otherwise I want the entire file.

I googled about this for an hour or two, but all I found was things synchronously reading an entire file at a time, or reading pieces at a time asynchronously.

Thanks!

Here's the Python:

```
def readPrefix(filename: str) -> str:
    with open(filename, 'rb') as infile:
        data = infile.read(1024)
    return data
```

Here's the nodejs attempt:

```
const readPrefix = (filename: string): string => {
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(filename, { highWaterMark: 1024 });
    const data = readStream.read(1024);
    readStream.close();

    return data;
};
```

Comment: Well, to start with streams are asynchronous ONLY so you can't use a file stream to read anything synchronously.  You will need to use `fs.openSync()` and `fs.readSync()` and `fs.closeSync()` if you want to do file I/O synchronously.

Comment: If this is being done in a server context, then you really MUST do all I/O asynchronously in node.js or you ruin the scalability.  A stand-alone script that only ever does just one thing could do synchronous file I/O just fine, but not a server intended to server the needs of many requests.  If you showed the larger task you're trying to accomplish, we could show you how to use node.js asynchronous to meet the needs of your task.

Comment: I really do just want synchronous for this program - it's less bug prone, and performance isn't an issue in this case.  Do I need to loop on readSync() in case of EINTR or something?

Comment: I'm not using cooperative multitasking.  In fact, I'm not using multitasking of any kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read synchronously, you would use `fs.openSync()`, `fs.readSync()` and `fs.closeSync()`.

Here's some regular Javascript code (hopefully you can translate it to TypeScript) that synchronously reads a certain number of bytes from a file and returns a buffer object containing those bytes (or throws an exception in case of error):

```
const fs = require('fs');

function readBytesSync(filePath, filePosition, numBytesToRead) {
    const buf = Buffer.alloc(numBytesToRead, 0);
    let fd;

    try {
        fd = fs.openSync(filePath, "r");
        fs.readSync(fd, buf, 0, numBytesToRead, filePosition);
    } finally {
        if (fd) {
            fs.closeSync(fd);
        }
    }
    return buf;
}
```

For your application, you can just pass 1024 as the bytes to read and if there are less than that in the file, it will just read up until the end of the file.  The returns buffer object will contain the bytes read which you can access as binary or convert to a string.

For the benefit of others reading this, I mentioned in earlier comments that synchronous I/O should never be used in a server environment (servers should always use asynchronous I/O except at startup time).  Synchronous I/O can be used for stand-alone scripts that only do one thing (like build scripts, as an example) and don't need to be responsive to multiple incoming requests.

> Do I need to loop on readSync() in case of EINTR or something?

Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @dstromberg - Does this answer your question?

Comment: Almost.  When I create fd inside the try block, I get a "TS2304: Cannot find name 'fd'" from tsc.

Comment: @dstromberg - If you mean "move the definition of `fd` inside the `try` block", then that would be expected because the `finally` clause needs to access `fd` to it has to be defined at a higher scope so it can be seen in both places it is used.  If you mean something different, I would have to see the actual code in order to help.